# Проблема при ширине viewport 320px

Tags: html, css, media-queries

**Появился странный отступ при ширине viewport 320px.
Подскажите в чем проблема и где его найти?**
[image: Вот этот отступ]

[Ссылка на проект](http://catering.co.ua/)

Comment: [ссылка](http://catering.co.ua/)

Comment: найти его можно в браузере через отладчик

Comment: @lexxl Смотрел ничего не нашел можете отправить скрин?

Comment: проверил в chrome и в ff, проблем как у вас на скриншоте не обнаружил.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov  Проблема в том, что в браузере все нормально. а на телефоне отступ...

Comment: @Alexandr у меня не видно такого отступа, ищите у себя

Comment: @Alexandr на телефоне у вас ацкий трэш. Самое первое что бросилось в глаза - белый блок с кругами, он катастрофически неадаптивный. Ну и в остальных блоках каша мала...